# vi (vim) to read an exrc file other than ~/.exrc

Tags: unix, vim, vi, ex

We would like to be able to start vi (or vim) up with an alternative ex initialisation file.  By default this is ~/.exrc.

Unfortunately vim(1), which is also brought up for "man ex" on this system, doesn't mention .exrc.

Any workarounds to provide equivalent behaviour would also be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are dealing with an ancient version of vi. What version are you using (`vi --version`)?

Comment: Just tried to `strace` Vims ex: it does not touch anything like .exrc

Comment: glts: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jul 12 2010 12:49:33).

Comment: fork0: On my Debian 6.0 system, with ex a symlink to vim.basic, "strace ex  2>&1 | grep exrc" yields a stat and an open on ~/.exrc

Comment: I think vim reads `.exrc` if `.vimrc` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I was expecting the common `-u conf_file` to work, but that fails here. A workaround is to load no configuration file with `-u NONE` and then source the one you want with `-c`:

```
ex -u NONE -c 'source your_local_exrc'
```

Comment: Thanks Thor.  That was enough info to find what I was after, which is "vi -u NONE -S your_local_exrc".  Because -c is for commands, whereas -S sources the file.  I also now see that detailed documentation for this is available by running ":help init" from within vim.  My initial search for exrc within the man page wasn't sufficient.

Comment: I meant to say `-c 'source your_local_exrc'` (fixed it now), but `-S` is even better :).

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of traditional vi/ex use the `EXINIT` environment variable as a command string to execute on startup, and execute `$HOME/.exrc` if it is not set.  If you're running such a version, you can set `EXINIT` to `so /other/file/to/execute` to source an alternate startup file.

Comment: Thanks.  Now that I've found ":help init" from within vim, I see that the EXINIT environment variable, and its precedence over ~/.exrc, is indeed documented there.

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.exrc` (for vi) file add following lines at start

```
set exrc   " Dangerous
set secure " Disables shell and write commands in .exrc/.vimrc
```

This will make sure that the `.exrc` file from the current directory will be loaded if it exists.